# How to add macro under visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, macros, cocos2d-x, visual-studio-macros, cocos2d-x-3.0

I just found that cocos2d-x 3.0 beta has defined own macro "$(EngineRoot)" under vs2012 proj, I want to know how to do it!
I can not upload the img...

Comment: `Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions`?

Comment: VS has already defined a lot of macros, like `$(ProjectDir)`, `$(SolutionDir)` etc. What are your macros used for?

Comment: I just foundt the answer，just add in props file

Comment: You can post the answer below (answer your own question) so that others can learn. :)

Comment: sorry I dont have enough reputation...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you generate a cocos2d project using the cocos.py script as recommended in the docs, you'll find that EngineRoot is defined in the project's cocos2d_headers.props file near the top as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
  <EngineRoot>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\</EngineRoot>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You should be able to do the same in your own (non-generated) project.